# How do I stop "default programs" from popping up all the time with Chrome?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

I've got a machine where Edge is the default browser and Chrome is used as a secondary for a specific website that requires it.  The issue is that every time Chrome starts up, the Windows 10 default programs control panel also starts up.  It's very annoying.  This was not a problem with Firefox which was the prior secondary browser.  It's a new behavior since switching to Chrome as the secondary.  The primary/secondary browsers are for specific website usage/compatibility reasons, so that can't change.

I've tried selecting Edge as the default and closing the box.  Still, every start of Chrome pops it again.  I've also run down through the Chrome settings screen, but the only default area I can find simply says that Chrome is not the default.  I don't see any alert options like were common back in the day.

What can I do to prevent Chrome from causing this popup every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Add "--no-default-browser-check" switch to shortcut.

For default installation paths target would be:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --no-default-browser-check

Sadly, its seems that's all we can do about it for now.

---

Default Chrome behavior is to ask for default browser change first in small bar below address bar, if this prompt is skipped you might want to reinstall/reset Chrome.